# How to use Imagemagick to convert a multi-page pdf to B&W while maintaining readability?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

[image]I have been trying to convert a multi-page color pdf to 2-color B&W (not grayscale).

Some research turned up the following command:

```
convert -posterize 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

which worked, in that it turned the gray pages white and the text pure black, but the text was unreadable. Further research turned up the following modification:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -posterize 2 input.pdf -density 300 output.pdf
```

but the results were the same. The characters were pixelized and incomplete. How can I convert the pdf while keeping the same text quality? Note that the answer does not have to use Imagemagick. I am running Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon.

Comment: Post your example input and output images!

Comment: You need to use `-colors 2` rather than `-posterize 2` and put the `-density 300` right at the start of your command before loading the input PDF.

Comment: As Mark Setchell said, posterize is not the method you want. It "Reduce the image to a limited number of color levels **per channel**".  So for -posterize 2, you get 2 colors per each channel.  You want either -colors 2 (with or without dithering) or -monochrome, which will dither in IM 6, but not in IM 7.

Comment: I tried Mark Setchell's suggestion, and the result would not open.

Comment: I added a sample of the input/output. I can't post the document as it is hundreds of pages long.

Comment: @KJ I see where you are coming from, but as OP is suggesting **ImageMagick** himself, I presume he is happy with the PDF being fully rasterised already because that is what **ImageMagick** will always do.

Comment: @KJ Selecting, copying, and pasting text from the document produces correct output. However, doing so is very clunky and doing a "find" on the document in its current form is painfully slow.

Comment: @KJ I would be more than happy with it looking as you posted it on the docdroid site. How did you achieve that?

Comment: @KJ I extracted a page and put the file on transfer.sh. Let me know if you need more. https://transfer.sh/gpHbPIRm8b/bookpage.pdf